# Angularjs slick slider reinit

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

I want to reinitialize slick slider so i created following methods for destroy and for init.But it doesn't works for me please suggest me any solution to reinitialize slider from controller

```
$scope.initSlick = function () {
        $scope.slickConfig2Loaded = true;
        $scope.slickConfig2 = {
            autoplay: true,
            infinite: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 5,
            waitForAnimate: false,
            method: {}
        };

    }

    $scope.destroySlick = function () {
        if ($scope.slickConfig2Loaded) {
            $scope.slickConfig2.method.unslick();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Could you add other codes like HTML and which step do you want to reinitialize it?

Comment: Issue is i want to reload the slider but it doesnt work, if you have any other solution please suggest me